# Creation of many unit tests in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I like being able to [create a unit test](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html) for a class in IntelliJ.  Is it possible to create unit tests on a larger scale, e.g., for an entire module?  If it is, does IntelliJ skip test creation for any class that already has tests?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition 2019.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The reasoning is that it doesn't make sense to create a unit test class without writing some unit tests in it, and one can only write unit tests for one class at a time. And if you go over classes one at a time, invoking the "create test" shortcut for the class takes much less time than writing the test, so there's not much to be saved from performing this operation in batch.

Comment: I understand that reasoning.  This question is actually a starting point for a larger idea - generating more intelligent unit tests.  If I'm smart enough, maybe I can hook into IntelliJ somehow and create good tests for each method under test.  Ideally, I could click on a module a generate a bunch of good tests.  But even if all that is too ambitious, it is nice to be able to generate a lot of boilerplate code for an entire module with a single action rather than doing that action 30 times for each of the 30 files in a module.

Comment: We generally prefer not to implement actions that generate 30 files of meaningless boilerplate. You can of course write a plugin to implement any kind of test generation that you find valuable.